# after update to ios10, Alamofire4 request brings error status 401

Tags: alamofire, http-status-code-401

After updating to xcode8 Alamofire4, my AlamofireRequest is not working, returning " status code: 401, headers" (unauthorised) on the request. The user authorisation is correct (I have checked the site).  I do not have any compiler errors, but note that 'headers' is not highlighted in blue as usual, so am thinking that it is not recognising the headers properly. Am I doing something wrong with the 'headers' here?

```
   let user = "sampleUser"
    let password = "samplepass"
    let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    var checkUserEndpoint: String = "https://sample.com/ios1/user/\(uidEntered!).json"

    print(checkUserEndpoint)

    Alamofire.request(checkUserEndpoint, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)
                print(response.response)
                print(response.data)
```

I have already tried using this instead for the headers, but it made no difference:

```
     var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }
```

also I tried this and it made no difference;

```
 Alamofire.request(checkUserEndpoint,
                      method: .get,
                      parameters: nil,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)

        .authenticate(user: "sampleUser", password: "samplepass")
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)
                print(response.response)
                print(response.data)
              //  print(response.error)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar migration twice, and my educated guess is that one of your strings you pass to generate headers value is Optional, ie. `user`, `password` or `base64Credentials`; though generating Optional("thestring") instead "thestring". You can try to wrap the request like this:

```
if let user = user, password = password, base64Credentials = base64Credentials {
     let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    var checkUserEndpoint: String = "https://sample.com/ios1/user/\(uidEntered!).json"

    print(checkUserEndpoint)

    Alamofire.request(checkUserEndpoint, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)
                print(response.response)
                print(response.data) 
}
```

This can happen eg. in a situation, where those values coming from the Objective-C code, where the variables are not marked `nonnull`.

... `base64Credentials` should not be optional though, as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct in both variants (manual header creation and Alamofire request .authenticate usage). Looks like server side issue, use curl/postman or any other REST client to receive success response from your server before continuing your app development.